# Is the following formula in CTL welformed?

Tags: logic, formula, parse-tree, ctl

The formula is the following:

```
AF A[(p U q) --> (r U q)]
```

The answer is no, but why?

*Said, not a valid formula. The subformula starting with the innermost A does not conform to the type A (x U y).*

Is not the path quantifier 'A' for the entire paranthesis (both formulas)?

Answer (score 0):

The CTL operator is

> **A[** P **U** Q **]**

The parser is unable to find out what is **P** and what is **Q** in your formula because the only possible choices are either

- **P :=** *"(p "* and **Q :=** *" q) --> (r U q)"*, or
- **P :=** *"(p U q) --> (r "* and **Q :=** *" q)"*

and in either case both **P** and **Q** are malformed formulas.